# Correlation between boolean and continues value

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I was wondering, if I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns.
The first on is a boolean and the others are float.

If I run .corr() on my dataframe, how should interpret the answer? 
For exampel:

```
corr_matrix = df.corr()
corr_matrix["Bought"].abs().sort_values(ascending=False)

Bought         1.000000
Price          0.283186
Price2         0.118623
```

Could one say that "Price" correlates more with the "Bought" flag and will then affect the model more then "Price2"?

How could I otherwise decide what price to use in my model?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103801/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-pearson-or-spearman-correlation-between-two-boolea) helps?

Comment: According to that, neither Pearson or Spearman are good to use. Which the corr() function uses, if im not mistaken. How can I check correlations in pandas for this problem then`?

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021380/is-there-a-way-to-test-correlation-between-data-x-and-binary-output-y) - which might be the same thing you're asking for

Comment: Gentle reminder folks - don't post answers (even if they are only potential answers) in the comments, and please don't only post links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking for the point-biserial correlation ([which is a special case of Pearson correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105542/proof-of-point-biserial-correlation-being-a-special-case-of-pearson-correlation)). If you genuinely have to use pandas without any other library then I think the Pearson correlation *should* work, just by encoding your true/false as 1 and 0.

Comment: I tried this one scipy.stats.pointbiserialr(x, y), it uses pearson gives the same result for my data. But I also get the p-vaule. So I guess .corr() is ok